# Unable to Display Text From HTML Dynamic Table via JavaScript Alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
 function DataBind(dataList) {
        alert('working' + dataList.length);

        var SetData = $("#setdata");
        SetData.empty();

        for (var a = 0; a < dataList.length; a++) {
            var data = "<tr >" +

                "<th>" + dataList[a].Item_code + "</th>" +
                "<th id='ItmNm'>" + dataList[a].Item_Name + "</th>" +
                "<th>1</th> <th><button type='button'  onclick='addItem(" + dataList[a].Item_code + ")' class='btn btn-primary'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'/></button> <button type='button'  class='btnSelect'  class='btn btn-primary'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'/></button></th>"
                + "</tr>";

            // alert(dataList[a].Acc_Cd);
            SetData.append(data);
        }
    }

 function addItem(val) {

        //var theTbl = document.getElementById("myTable");
        //for (var i = 0; i < theTbl.length; i++) {

        //    for (var j = 0; j < theTbl.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
        //        theTbl.rows[i].cells[j] = alertInnerHTML;
        //    }
        //}


                alert(val);
                var table2 = $("#setfinaldata");
                table2.empty();
                var Newdata = "<tr>" +

                          "<th>" + val + "</th>" +
                          "<th> 1 </th>" +
                          "<th>1</th>"
                          + "</tr>";
                table2.append(Newdata);

    }
```

In this code variable val display item code on alert but item name not displayed

Comment: You won't click on button and get value?

Comment: you are passing only item code while calling addItem function on click of button then how will you get item name. You need to pass both to get it in function

Comment: bro i am clicking button and it shows only item code but not showing item name as i have tried hard but unable

Comment: @bhushan Kawadkar sir  i am already tried to pass item name but unable to get please specify method that how i can do this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass item name while calling addItem method, see below code

```
function DataBind(dataList) {
        alert('working' + dataList.length);

        var SetData = $("#setdata");
        SetData.empty();

        for (var a = 0; a < dataList.length; a++) {
            var data = "<tr >" +

                "<th>" + dataList[a].Item_code + "</th>" +
                "<th id='ItmNm'>" + dataList[a].Item_Name + "</th>" +
                "<th>1</th> <th><button type='button'  onclick=\"addItem('" + dataList[a].Item_code + "','" + dataList[a].Item_Name + "')\" class='btn btn-primary'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'/></button> <button type='button'  class='btnSelect'  class='btn btn-primary'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'/></button></th>"
                + "</tr>";

            // alert(dataList[a].Acc_Cd);
            SetData.append(data);
        }
    }

 function addItem(val, name) {  
                alert("Code = " + val + " and Name = " + name);
                var table2 = $("#setfinaldata");
                table2.empty();
                var Newdata = "<tr>" +

                          "<th>" + val + "</th>" +
                          "<th> 1 </th>" +
                          "<th>1</th>"
                          + "</tr>";
                table2.append(Newdata);

    }
```

Comment: I have tried updated code but its seems not working as i click the button nothing happens even item code not showing this time.

Comment: Still consfused that why item code is showing but unable to get alert of item name.

Comment: Its Partially works as:onclick=addItem(" + dataList[a].Item_code + ",'" + dataList[a].Item_Name + "')  i got name  just like (Code = 18070048 and Name = FAJITA) but still not able to get alert of text which has two words (i.e BBQ Cheese)

Comment: I have updated my post with escaping double qoutes and separate values with single quotes while calling addItem, please try this anwer

Comment: happy to help you :).. you can accept and upvote if find this answer useful

Answer (score 0):

You can try this example I'm created also refer to this link [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/prnzxubq/1/)

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="zui-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ItemCode</th>
            <th>Name</th>  
             <th>Action</th>  
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="jsTableBody">

    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 var dataList = [];
 dataList.push({
 Item_code : 1,
 Item_Name : "A"

 },{
 Item_code : 2,
 Item_Name : "B"

 },{
 Item_code : 3,
 Item_Name : "C"

 });
 var oHtml=[];
 for(var i=0;i<dataList.length;i++)
 {

 oHtml.push("<tr>");
 oHtml.push("<td>");
 oHtml.push(dataList[i].Item_code);
 oHtml.push("</td>");
 oHtml.push("<td>");
 oHtml.push(dataList[i].Item_Name);
 oHtml.push("</td>");
 oHtml.push("<td>"); 
 oHtml.push("<button onclick='addItem("+dataList[i].Item_code+",\""+dataList[i].Item_Name+"\");' class='jsButton'>Add</button>"); 
 oHtml.push("</td>");
 oHtml.push("</tr>");
 }
 $(".jsTableBody").html(oHtml.join(" "));
})

function addItem(data)
{
 alert(data);
}
</script>
```

Comment: siddiqui "Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details."

Comment: Your code is just showing item code in alert not showing item name as this is my main concern

Comment: In your link you have updated table via array but in my case i have to update table via json service datatable..your link is not feasible at the moment

Comment: Yes you can go with there no problems